# OpenID / Identity provider for self-hosting

Tags: linux, self-hosted, authentication, openid

I'm currently looking for a good (ideally Open Source) OpenID / Identity provider which can be hosted on my own servers. I want to use it as an OpenID provider for a login system which shares the login (for SSO) across multiple applications. Each user registers on the main site and will be able to use all different applications using the SSO provided from the OpenID provider.

I'm also aware that I can just use Facebook, Twitter, OpenId etc. But I don't want to force the users to use foreign authentication services due to the nature of the provided services.

It would be great if there is some kind of list or review over a good proven system.

For the technical information:

- Linux-based servers (CentOS/RedHat).
- Currently the server which is designated for the OpenID provider is just plain. Which means aside of the core setup there's nothing else on the machine.
- A web-interface for the OpenID system is appreciated but not a must have feature.

Comment: Haven't used it, so just a comment: https://packages.debian.org/testing/web/simpleid If you try it and find it useful, please post an answer.

Comment: Hm I don't think that this will work properly. As it's a debian package which won't really work on CentOS/RedHat based systems.

Comment: You might want to look out for relevant packages on your system.

Comment: Related question, but also accepting solutions for a single user: [OpenID provider for single user (self-hosted and free/libre)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25252/60)

Comment: In theory, MediaWiki can do this. I've not heard from users. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID

Answer (score 1):

The answer here depends mostly on what framework you are already using. PHP? Drupal? Python? Django? All of those have their own answers.

- [SimpleID](http://www.simpleid.org/): PHP, standalone
- [Drupal OpenID provider](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_provider): PHP, [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) based, I used it to connect OpenID with LDAP
- Python has a lot of alternatives, see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123369/whats-the-best-solution-for-openid-with-django) for details

You also didn't mention which *version* of OpenID you want to be deployed. New versions like [OpenID connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) are radically different than previous ones... So to answer this correctly, we'd need more information here...