# OpenID provider for single user (self-hosted and free/libre)

Tags: linux, open-source, self-hosted, authentication, openid

I want to become my own OpenID provider.

I need it primarily for logging into sites using [OpenID 2.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html). For older sites, support of [OpenID 1.1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html) would be great. I don’t know much about the new [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), so I’ll leave that open.

I would prefer if only one user is supported ([there’s a question for a multi-user OpenID provider](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21105/60)), in the hope that it’s more lightweight (which would make it easier to audit the software, should the need arise), that it gives less attack surface, and that it works without a database.

#### Formal requirements

- It must be licensed under a FLOSS license.
- It must still be maintained.
- It must run on a GNU/Linux server.

#### What I found

- [phpMyID](http://siege.org/phpmyid) is "no longer developed or maintained".
- [Prairie](http://barnraiser.org/prairie) seems to be dead (according to the filename of the current version 0.2 Alpha, it is from 2008).
- [OleKEH’s prairie-openid2-server](https://github.com/OleKEH/prairie-openid2-server) (started as a fork of Prairie) seems to be dead (last code change from 2011).
- [poit](http://yangman.ca/poit/) seems to be dead (last release from 2009).
- [SimpleID](http://simpleid.koinic.net/) sounds good (although it supports multiple users; but at least it’s not using a database) and doesn’t seem to be dead (last release from 2014-11; last site activity from 2015-04).

  (I will try this one unless I get other recommendations; of course, feel free to come up with an answer if you can recommend SimpleID for my purpose.)

Comment: What's the difference to  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21105/openid-identity-provider-for-selfhosting ?

Comment: @FrederickNord: As I wrote, I’ll accept and prefer solutions for only one user, while OP of the linked question looks for multi-user solutions.

Comment: @Tom: (As you seem to have created the [tag:self-hosted] tag -- did you see the Meta discussion [Tags for software that runs on a (web?) server](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/933/60)? If not, maybe you want to chime in.)

Comment: @unor I did and viewed your answer, is this not the best way to go about this?

Comment: @Tom: Okay, alright; I thought maybe you have a suggestion for improvement or a different idea or something like that. (I guess a score of +4/0 is not quite enough for starting such a big retagging event.)

Comment: Sure, I understand - your answer I believe does make the most sense; though

Answer (score 1):

For my own site, I used what basically amounts to OpenID forwarding. My site is built using [ikiwiki](https://ikiwiki.info/) so I use the [meta](http://ikiwiki.info/ikiwiki/directive/meta/) directive to add an OpenID delegation to another domain. This ends up creating the following HTML code in the [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head):

```
<link href="https://login.launchpad.net/+openid" rel="openid.server" />
<link href="https://login.launchpad.net/+openid" rel="openid2.provider" />
<link href="https://login.launchpad.net/+id/xxxxxxx" rel="openid.delegate" />
<link href="https://login.launchpad.net/+id/xxxxxxx" rel="openid2.local_id" />
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="https://login.launchpad.net/+id/xxxxxxx/+xrds" />
```

So you can see here I delegate to [Canonical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_(company))'s [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) but I could also have used any other OpenID provider I have an account on, including Stack  Exchange:

```
<!-- OpenID-2.0 delegated to stackexchange -->
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider" />
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" />
```

The Indieweb folks have an [excellent tutorial](https://indieweb.org/How_to_set_up_OpenID_on_your_own_domain) on how to do this forwarding. There are also [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-openid-delegation/), [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/openidurl) and probably other plugins that do this for you. But honestly, considering how simple the HTML code is, I would argue that it may be simpler to just have a static HTML page pointing to another provider than using a plugin.

I have looked at running my own OpenID provider as well, lightweight, without a database and all that. I ended up cheating like this: seems much simpler. After Google and even free software projects (e.g. [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid)) basically abandoned OpenID, I wasn't sure about the future of OpenID so I didn't want to spend too much efforts on it.

I know OpenID delegation isn't exactly like running your own provider, but considering that you didn't want to run a database and this is single user, I feel that just running a virtual host with a static page basically amounts to the same thing. You still need to run a webserver so I could argue you *are* running an OpenID provider. It 's just an implementation detail that the request is forwarded to another one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While it’s no solution for me (because I really want to be the provider, as in: don’t give a third-party data about me, don’t have to search another service in case they shut down, etc.), your answer can certainly be an alternative for people that don’t require it.

Comment: well that's the thing: if the provider shuts down, you just have to point to another provider in the delegation. as for the data, I already *have* that account there: the extra data I give out to launchpad is which sites I connect to, when and where from.

Comment: I know, that’s why I said "search", as I would have to find a third-party service again (and again …), possibly finding no trustable one anymore (and in my case, I won’t even find a single trustable one the first time, hence my question :)).